# Multiple usage of method in PHP

Tags: php, methods

I just wondering if is it a good practice to allow multiple datatypes as parameters of a method or function which will process the input data differently but in overall it will behave the same way and will return similar results. It is important to mention that I use PHP so I cannot overload methods and I can pass any datatype to an argument because of PHP's type juggling ability. To make easier to understand what I want, here is an example:

```
$form = new Form(); // This is a class which helps manage and process form fields of the $_POST
$form->fetch('user_name'); // Returns the value of the field named user_name as a string ($_POST['user_name'])
$form->fetch(); // If nothing is given as parameter it will return the whole fieldset of the form (whole content of $_POST as an array)
```

So my question is that is it a good practice to do this, or should I create a `fetchAll()` method.

Or an other example: `$page->getPageDataDetails(1)` will return an array containing the detailed data of page with the id:1. Like:

```
array(
  'id' => 1,
  'name' => 'foo'
)
```

While `$page->getPageDataDetails()` will return detailed data of all pages like:

```
array(
   0 =>  array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'foo'
         )

   1 =>  array(
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'bar'
         ) 

   2 =>  array(
            'id' => 5,
            'name' => 'something'
         )
)
```

So the function works with the same logic (I mean semantically the same behavior) but the format of output depends on the format of the input.
Is this a good idea?

Comment: This is a question of personal preference, I guess. There is no ONE way to do this. I personally would prefer the `fetchAll()` approach, because it's better and clearer. Hiding different behavior behind different parameters can lead to all sorts of confusing errors.

Comment: I recommend against it. Functions that expect a parameter should get one, or throw an error. This provides consistency and allows for proper unit testing

Comment: Depends on you but adding more meaningfull name to methods may help later. `$form->fethcParam()` `$form->fetchAllParams()`

Comment: A possibility is to use `gettype` to identitfy the type of the variable. With that type you can use a factory method (or just static) to create an instance of a class which will handle the method. The disadvantage of this, is that you need to create a class hierarchy to catch the different datatypes. Another option is to store functions in an array, which you can call based on the type of the variable. So if the type 'string' is stored in an array with the function 'fetchString', you can call it with e.g. `call_user_func($functions['string'], 'Your variable here');` .

Answer (score 1):

It's depends on you and your code, because if it's a public method the good way is a create exclude method like `->getItem($Id)` and `->getItems()`

But now if your code it's not in good condition and you want to create separate method to get allItems
and you copy and paste whole code from one method to second and change only few lines, it's not a good practice, it's a perfect !DRY.

I recommend to create private method like `->get()` and create a public alias to this method like `->getItem($id)` and `->getItems()`
to minify your code and get it cleanly.

It's only my opinion

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is to make it clear in your code that there are multiple usages of the function. Both forms should be completely explicit about the type of arguments they take and should be documented separately.

In my experience, this helps keep things organized and makes debugging easier:

```php
function fetch($name = null) {

    if (is_string($name)) {

        /*

            Returns the value of the field named user_name as a string ($_POST['user_name'])

            @param name the user name

        */

        // Code here

    } else if (is_null($name)) {


    /*

        Returns the whole fieldset of the form (whole content of $_POST as an array)

    */

    // Code here

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what Im doing right now. Just wondering if is it a good or bad idea...

Comment: @ACs My point is, there's nothing inherently "good" or "bad" about it; what's important is that you keep the code organized. (P.S. I also do this kind of overloading - it helps to keep function names semantic, which simplifies your API. If you're worried that it's a bad practice, I'd personally argue that it isn't)